# Exporting a highchart from the cmdline with phantomjs

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to export a highchart graph from the command line, following the steps the highchart website gives here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside

It always fails with this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts
```

In more detail, the steps they are give are just these:

1. Download and install phantomjs
2. Save these files all to one location: highcharts-convert.js, highcharts.js, highcharts-more.js, jquery
3. Good to go.

So, I followed the above steps as shown here:

First,  install phantomjs:

```
>npm install -g phantomjs
```

verify install:

```
>phantomjs -v
1.9.7
```

Second, save indicated files in one location, as you can see here I have:

```
>ls

data.js  highcharts-convert.js  highcharts.js    map.js options.json
highcharts-3d.js    highcharts-more.js  jquery.1.9.1.min.js readme.md
```

Third, I should be good to go, but ... :

A. their sample command requires an "options.json" file to provide the options in. I couldn't find documentation for this on their site, but googling it, my options.json file looks like this:

```
>more options.json

{
    "xAxis": {
            "categories": ["Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },
    "series": [{
            "data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
}
```

B. run the example command line provided on the highcharts page:

```
>phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options.json -outfile chart.png -scale 2.5 -width 300

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts

 highcharts-more.js:51
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts

  data.js:16
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts

phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():81
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():150
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():150
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
ERROR: While rendering, there's is a timeout reached
```

Note that I also tried editing the highcharts-convert.js script to provide the full path for the highcharts and jquery files, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In the highcharts-convert.js you have list of all files which are loaded by server, if you have missing highcharts-more and others you receive errors. I advice you to comment files which you dont use.

Comment: Hi, do you know why when I'm exporting the highchart server-side I have a black image? I followed the same instruction but always I have black image with even export button shown in the image

Comment: Could you paste your chart configuration and let me know if you use styled mode or not?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I solved the issue actually but I may need more help to make this as a service, so I can send a request with data and chart creation JavaScript file and save the output image to S3, do you have any idea how to do that in an easy way?

Comment: Being honest Im not server developer, but from Highcharts you can extract SVG (chart.getSVG() method) and then convert it to image on your server, saving it.